# how to add some extra field in registration form in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i want to add some extra field in my registration form in wordpress site how to add it.and made entry in database.
hope some one help me.thanks

Comment: Voting to close: This is much too hazy to be answered seriously. But have you looked at Wordpress' built-in custom fields functionality? http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields it may already do what you need

Answer (score 0):

I have used the plugin 'Cimy User extra fields' on several clients' sites and found that it does the job very well.

Last installed on a site within the last couple of months, so Wordpress 3 support is fine.

Comment: How to access fields later somewhere on profile page, created by 'Cimy User extra fields'

Comment: That all depends on what you mean by 'access'. For example, the custom fields are visible in each user's profile.